# XML::CanonicalizeXML Perl package install on Windows

Tags: c++, xml, windows, perl, compiler-errors

I'm new to Perl and I started working on a project which needs some modules. One of them is [`XML::CanonicalizeXML`](https://WWW.metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aCanonicalizeXML) that can't seem to be installed.

I'm using Strawberry Perl and CPAN for package handling.

I tried manually compiling the package from the downloaded tar.gz file, but the same error has occurred that seems to be occuring in the g++ compilation:

```
  CPAN.pm: Building S/SJ/SJZASADA/XML-CanonicalizeXML-0.05.tgz

'xml2-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'xml2-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
'xml2-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'xml2-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
MakeMaker (v6.64)
Warning (non-fatal): Target 'dynamic' depends on targets in skipped section 'dyn
amic_lib'
Warning (non-fatal): Target 'static' depends on targets in skipped section 'stat
ic_lib'
Writing Makefile for Mytest2::canon
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Writing Makefile for XML::CanonicalizeXML
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp lib/XML/CanonicalizeXML.pm blib\lib\XML\CanonicalizeXML.pm
AutoSplitting blib\lib\XML\CanonicalizeXML.pm (blib\lib\auto\XML\CanonicalizeXML
)
cd canon && dmake
gcc -c  -I.     -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -
DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2     -DVERSION=\"\"
        -DXS_VERSION=\"\"  "-IC:\strawberry\perl\lib\CORE"   canon.c
ar cr libcanon.a canon.o
rem libcanon.a
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe C:\strawberry\perl\lib\ExtUtils\xsubpp  -typemap
 C:\strawberry\perl\lib\ExtUtils\typemap  CanonicalizeXML.xs > CanonicalizeXML.x
sc && C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e mv -- CanonicalizeX
ML.xsc CanonicalizeXML.c
Please specify prototyping behavior for CanonicalizeXML.xs (see perlxs manual)
gcc -c  -I.     -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -
DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2     -DVERSION=\"0.
05\"    -DXS_VERSION=\"0.05\"  "-IC:\strawberry\perl\lib\CORE"   CanonicalizeXML
.c
CanonicalizeXML.xs: In function 'XS_XML__CanonicalizeXML_canonicalize':
CanonicalizeXML.xs:28:17: warning: passing argument 6 of 'canonicalize' from inc
ompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
canon/canon.h:2:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'xmlChar **'

Running Mkbootstrap for XML::CanonicalizeXML ()
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e chmod -- 644 Canonicalize
XML.bs
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Mksymlists \
     -e "Mksymlists('NAME'=>\"XML::CanonicalizeXML\", 'DLBASE' => 'CanonicalizeX
ML', 'DL_FUNCS' => {  }, 'FUNCLIST' => [], 'IMPORTS' => {  }, 'DL_VARS' => []);"

dlltool --def CanonicalizeXML.def --output-exp dll.exp
g++ -o blib\arch\auto\XML\CanonicalizeXML\CanonicalizeXML.dll -Wl,--base-file -W
l,dll.base -mdll -s -L"C:\strawberry\perl\lib\CORE" -L"C:\strawberry\c\lib" Cano
nicalizeXML.o  canon/libcanon.a C:\strawberry\perl\lib\CORE\libperl516.a -lmoldn
ame -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole
32 -loleaut32 -lnetapi32 -luuid -lws2_32 -lmpr -lwinmm -lversion -lodbc32 -lodbc
cp32 -lcomctl32 dll.exp
CanonicalizeXML.o:CanonicalizeXML.c:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `xmlIn
itParser'
CanonicalizeXML.o:CanonicalizeXML.c:(.text+0x15c): undefined reference to `xmlSt
rlen'
CanonicalizeXML.o:CanonicalizeXML.c:(.text+0x189): undefined reference to `_imp_
_xmlFree'
CanonicalizeXML.o:CanonicalizeXML.c:(.text+0x190): undefined reference to `xmlCl
eanupParser'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `xmlStrle
n'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `_imp__xm
lMalloc'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `xmlParse
Memory'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `__xmlLoa
dExtDtdDefaultValue'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `xmlSubst
ituteEntitiesDefault'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `xmlParse
Memory'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x104): undefined reference to `xmlDocG
etRootElement'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x13a): undefined reference to `xmlStrE
qual'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x146): undefined reference to `xmlNode
GetContent'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `xmlXPat
hNewContext'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x194): undefined reference to `xmlXPat
hRegisterNs'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x1ca): undefined reference to `_imp__x
mlFree'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x1d4): undefined reference to `xmlXPat
hFreeContext'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x1dc): undefined reference to `xmlFree
Doc'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x1e4): undefined reference to `_imp__x
mlRealloc'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x238): undefined reference to `xmlFree
Doc'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x27d): undefined reference to `xmlXPat
hEvalExpression'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x28d): undefined reference to `_imp__x
mlFree'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x2a2): undefined reference to `xmlXPat
hFreeContext'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x2aa): undefined reference to `xmlFree
Doc'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x2db): undefined reference to `xmlC14N
DocDumpMemory'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x2e7): undefined reference to `xmlXPat
hFreeObject'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x2f3): undefined reference to `xmlFree
Doc'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x301): undefined reference to `xmlMemo
ryDump'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x393): undefined reference to `xmlFree
Doc'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x435): undefined reference to `xmlFree
Doc'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x46e): undefined reference to `_imp__x
mlFree'
canon/libcanon.a(canon.o):canon.c:(.text+0x478): undefined reference to `xmlFree
Doc'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'blib\arch\auto\XML\CanonicalizeXML\Can
onicalizeXML.dll'
  SJZASADA/XML-CanonicalizeXML-0.05.tgz
  C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'XML::CanonicalizeXML'.
Failed during this command:
 SJZASADA/XML-CanonicalizeXML-0.05.tgz        : make NO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the CPAN only downloaded the UNIX Shell script version of the xml2-config that needed to be replaced with a Windows batch file. If anyone else needs it here it is:

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem http://batcheero.blogspot.co.il/2007/06/how-to-enabledelayedexpansion.html - windows xp

SET SELFDIR=%~dp0
IF %SELFDIR:~-1%==\ SET SELFDIR=%SELFDIR:~0,-1%
set SELFDIR=%SELFDIR:\=/%

set prefix=%SELFDIR%
set exec_prefix=%prefix%
set includedir=%prefix%/include
set libdir=%exec_prefix%/lib

IF "%1"=="" GOTO usage0

rem whats the point of resettingthes flags...
rem set cflags=false
rem set libs=false

:loop

    IF "%1"=="" Exit /B 0

    IF "%1"=="--version" (
    echo 2.4.12
    Exit /B 0
    )

    IF "%1"=="--help" (
          GOTO usage0
    )

    rem the code below does: if next arg is not any known argument nor empty then the next arg is prefix value otherwise print the prefix
    IF "%1"=="--prefix" ( 
          IF "%2"=="" ( SHIFT
                        echo %prefix%) ELSE (
            IF "%2"=="--cflags" ( SHIFT
                                  echo %prefix% ) ELSE (
              IF "%2"=="--libs" ( SHIFT
                                  echo %prefix%) ELSE (
                IF "%2"=="--prefix" ( SHIFT
                                      echo %prefix%) ELSE (
                 SET /A prefix=%2
                 set exec_prefix=!prefix!
                 set includedir=!prefix!/include
                 set libdir=!exec_prefix!/lib
                 SHIFT
                 SHIFT
                )
              )
            )
          )
    )

    IF "%1"=="--cflags" (

        echo -I!includedir!/libxml2/libxml -I!includedir!/libxml2 
    SHIFT
    )

    IF "%1"=="--libs" (
        echo -L!libdir! -lxml2 -lz  -liconv -lm -Wl,-s -lwsock32 -liberty -lMsup -lMstubs 
    SHIFT
    )


    GOTO :loop

Exit /B 1


:usage0

echo Usage: xml-config [OPTION]
echo _
echo Known values for OPTION are:
echo _
echo   --prefix=DIR     change libxml prefix [default $prefix]
echo   --libs       print library linking information
echo   --cflags     print pre-processor and compiler flags
echo   --help       display this help and exit
echo   --version        output version information
Exit /B 0

:usage1

echo Usage: xml-config [OPTION]
echo _
echo Known values for OPTION are:
echo _
echo   --prefix=DIR     change libxml prefix [default $prefix]
echo   --libs       print library linking information
echo   --cflags     print pre-processor and compiler flags
echo   --help       display this help and exit
echo   --version        output version information
Exit /B 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `XML::CanonicalizeXML` module depends on `libxml2`. Since `xml2-config` is a `libxml2` command, it looks like you have `libxml2` installed incorrectly or not at all.

Comment: I've already downloaded it from http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/ and copied the contents to my strawberry/c/ directory and the readme says it doesn't need any special installation.

Comment: That's a strange place to put it. Anyway, the same `readme` file says *“...if you want to run the supplied utilities from the command
line, you can, if you wish, add XML::CanonicalizeXML 'bin' subdirectory to the PATH
environment variable”*. You can't just dump the release in a random place on your disk and expect it to work. The module installation is trying to run `xml2-config` and clearly it can't find d it.

Comment: It's not a random place that's where the g++ compiler is that the CPAN uses and where all the other c++ libs are. But I've also found the xml2-config there which was a unix shell script and after some Googling I've found the Windows bat file version of it and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's missing a required executable. Find out where the `xml2-config` program was installed (or placed), and [add that directory to your Windows PATH](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).